# Query current directory in Python (the one the script is running from)

Tags: python, path, directory, location

Is there any way to query the absolute path of a script inside the script we want to know the location for? For instance if I save it on my Desktop, I would like to store into a variable the absolute location, I want it to return `C:/Users/Doc/Desktop`.

I saw this piece of code in another guy's script but I don't know exactly if it is useful for what I am aiming to do: `path = os.path.dirname(script.__file__)`

Do you know how to implement that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the path of the current script, use:

```
__file__
```

To get the directory from that:

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

---

To get the current working directory (directory you were in when the script ran), use:

```
os.getcwd()
```

[os.getcwd documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getcwd)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `__file__` is what you are looking for; but it can be a relative path.

Use:

```
here = os.path.basename(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

to turn that into the directory path of the location of the script. [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) takes a relative path and turns it into an absolute path (using the current working directory as a reference); [`os.path.dirname()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) splits off the filename from that path.